# Rust ndarray type error: trait bound not implemented

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust

I'm using [ndarray](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.0/ndarray/) and [ndarray_einsum_beta](https://lib.rs/crates/ndarray_einsum_beta) to mimic [numpy.einsum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html).

I seem to be getting a type error trying to implement the basic example given:

```
let m1 = arr1(&[1, 2]);
let m2 = arr2(&[[1, 2], [3, 4]]);
println!("{:?}", einsum("i,ij->j", &[&m1, &m2]));
```

For both `m1` and `m2` I get the error:

> the trait bound `ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::OwnedRepr<{integer}>,
>   ndarray::Dim<[usize; 1]>>: ndarray_einsum_beta::ArrayLike<_>` is not
>   satisfied
>
> the trait `ndarray_einsum_beta::ArrayLike<_>` is not implemented for
>   `ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::OwnedRepr<{integer}>,
>   ndarray::Dim<[usize; 1]>>`
>
> note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn
>   ndarray_einsum_beta::ArrayLike<_>`rustc(E0277)

As shown in the console on compilcation:[image]

Whole `main.rs`:

```
use ndarray::prelude::*;
use ndarray_einsum_beta::*;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let m1 = arr1(&[1, 2]);
    let m2 = arr2(&[[1, 2], [3, 4]]);
    println!("{:?}", einsum("i,ij->j", &[&m1, &m2]));
}
```

Whole `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "clean_slate"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Jonathan <jonathanwoollettlight@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
ndarray = "0.13.0"
ndarray_einsum_beta = "0.4.4"
```

I really cannot figure what I have done wrong here, my best guess right now is perhaps a bad version combination of `ndarray` and `ndarray_eisum_beta`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently [`ndarray_einsum_beta`](https://github.com/oracleofnj/einsum) depends on `ndarray-0.12`. Changing the dependencies of your project solves the problem:

```
[dependencies]
ndarray = "0.12"
ndarray_einsum_beta = "0.4.4"
```